# Unable to get html file to display in UIWebView

Tags: xcode4, uiwebview

I am attempting to follow this example: http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/uiwebview-tutorial/239/

I have added a UIWebView into my view (using Storyboard)... I added the IBOutlet to my .h controller file. (see image at: http://imgur.com/GfUmC). I added a delegate to the view controller like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface slWebViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *slWebView;    
}

@end
```

Since I'm using XCode 4, I don't know how to set the UIWebView's delegate to the File Owner, which is why I think this is what I'm getting a black screen.  I'm missing something, but I don't know what.  At this point, I would really, really appreciate any help I can get solving this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Storyboard, right click (or ctrl-click) and drag from your UIWebView to the File's Owner on the left side, and choose "delegate".

Alternatively, select the webView (as in your image).  Note the top outlet, "delegate".  Drag from there to the File's Owner.

Or you can code it.  In viewDidLoad, type "self.sIWebView.delegate = self;"

All of this is assuming that you have your URL request right.  In case you don't, here's an example:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url  
                                                           cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData    
                                                       timeoutInterval: 10];
    [sIWebView loadRequest:request];
```

EDIT:  If you are presenting the webView modally, add this code to the view controller that segues to your webview: `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{ if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"]) { WebViewController *webView = segue.destinationViewController; webView.delegate = self; } }` You'll need to add an identifier to your segue. Just click on the segue itself, go to the third tab from the right, and type in an identifier.

UPDATE:  I've isolated the problem to the webViewConroller.m file. Everything is connected properly. If I place the loadRequest code in the viewController at viewDidLoad, I see Google. If I place the loadRequest code in the "webViewController", and mark the ViewContoller as a custom class of webViewController, I get the black screen. I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to get the UIWebView to display content? I really don't need a controller for the webView, just when the segue for that cell is tapped, display the contents of the UIWebView... not sure I can do it with XCode...

Comment: It didn't change a thing!  I've uploaded my code and a screen shot of what I'm seeing.  Hopefully you can see what I did wrong. :D

Code is here (there are 3 views) http://imgur.com/4GnfE,k667K,sQGVp

Comment: Copy this and paste it in your -viewDidLoad: `NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]; NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval: 10]; [slWebView loadRequest:request];`  Then load it and see what happens.  You don't have any code telling the webView what to display.

Comment: Nothing happens... it's still black.  FYI, in my app, there are two segues which get activated depending on which was chosen... they display different html, one from a file, the other program generated html.

I'm wondering if I should delete the UIWebView that is in the UIViewController and start again from the beginning?

Comment: I think I've got it... give me a few minutes to try it on my app (I made a test app and it worked!) brb

Comment: Nope!  It works in the sample, but I do the same thing in my app, and I get the black screen.  The only difference between the two is there is a segue going from another controller to my UIViewConroller which houses the UIWebView.  I'm at a loss as to why it works one place and not the other!?

Comment: What type of segue is it?  Add this code to the view controller that segues to your webview:  `-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"]) {
        WebViewController *webView = segue.destinationViewController;
        webView.delegate = self;
    }
}`  You'll need to add an identifier to your segue.  Just click on the segue itself, go to the third tab from the right, and type in an identifier.  This should solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding... had appointments in town today... I would like to get this fixed before the "bounty" expires! :D

I upload the pertinent code files here:http://imgur.com/bcRPR,2GIsf,1b8c7,pDgGC

I'm pretty sure we're getting close... I really appreciate your time and patience.  :D

Comment: Did you try my last recommendation?  If so, what was the outcome?

Comment: AMayes:  take a look at the 4 images I uploaded... I have an error that I don't understand... "use of undeclared identifier", which is not the case, unless I did it wrong.. (btw, I'm a newbie at Obj-C, if that helps :D)

Comment: Okay, so I assume you have a tableView that you want to use to push a webView-- that's the only sense I can make of what you've done.  Simply importing your webViewController.h file does not act as a declaration of "webView".  So tell me: are you pushing your webView using a tableView?

Comment: In any case, you should not be loading the webView in both the webViewController and the tableViewController.  The code should only be in the webViewController.  If the tableViewController is pushing the webViewController, you should not need the "prepareForSegue" code above.  But if it is presenting the webView modally, then you will need to include that code in the tableViewController.

Comment: Hi AMayes... yes, I am pushing the webView using a tableView, which has 7 views (storyboard image is here: http://imgur.com/PF5cS). I needed the "prepareForSegue" because I was trying earlier to use the one WebView for two different HTML files, depending on which segue was activated.  I'll remove the "prepareForSegue", just in case it's the culprit... I'll get back to you asap.

Comment: I removed the "prepareForSegue" and I still get the black screen... moved the "loadRequest" to -viewDidLoad in the webViewConroller... the code get's executed, but I get a black screen anyway.  The "prepareForSegue" does nothing when it's in the webViewController, whereas it does get executed in the tableViewController.

Comment: Okay.  Delete your webView declarations.  Go to the Assistant Editor (looks like a tuxedo in the upper right corner) and set the left side to your Storyboard and the right side to your .h file.  Right-click the webview and drag to your .h file.  name it "webView".  I can't see any of your connections in the imgur pics, so I don't know if everything is connected. Do you see on the left the name of your Controller class? Drag from your webView to that class, and select "delegate".  If you don't see it, click on the webViewController in your Storyboard, and set the class to "myWebViewController".

Comment: Try changing the timeoutInterval to a higher number.  I'm throwing everything I can think of at the wall to see what sticks.  Working with Storyboards is still a bit more complex than it needs to be, imho.

Comment: AMeyes: Since I had the UIWebView working in a prototype, I decided to start over.  The only problem I have now is that the "prepareForSegue" is not being executed, but that is probably because I don't have the .h or .m files in place for the webView.  I'm going to do that now, and if everything goes well, I'll have a segue that not only will get triggered, but load the webView accordingly.  I'll get back to you with progress... I really, really appreciate your help...

Comment: I've isolated the problem to the webViewConroller.m file.  Everything is connected properly.  If I place the loadRequest code in the viewController at viewDidLoad, I see Google.  If I place the loadRequest code in the "webViewController", and mark the ViewContoller as a custom class of webViewController, I get the black screen. I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to get the UIWebView to display content?  I really don't need a controller for the webView, just when the segue for that cell is tapped, display the contents of the UIWebView... not sure I can do it with XCode...  Any ideas?

Comment: Quick question--when you went to change the class name of your ViewController, did you have to type it in, or could you select it?

Comment: I selected it... but now with all the farkeling around I have been doing, I only get a white screen... might have to start over again! What a PITA!

Comment: OK... started over, added the UIWebView and a UITableView.  Put some labels in the tableview cell, embedded the tableview in a navigation controller.  Made the navController initial view controller and finally, added the code to load the webview at the tableViewControllers "viewDidLoad"... works like a champ!  I'm only sorry you had to go through this!  Thank you so very much... I truly appreciate it!

Comment: Please edit any relevant information from the comments into the question and/or answer.